# vgaswitcheroo not available on cold boot, only after restart

Tags: 12.04, vgaswitcheroo

I am running the new Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit release on my MSI CX420 laptop. It has 2 GPUs, an ATI and an Intel integrated one.

So my problem is that, whenever I start my laptop for the first time, vgaswitcheroo does not seem to be loaded as the path

```
/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

does not exist yet my ATI card seems to be powered still and heats up my laptop to a painful to the hands degree. However, when I restart the computer, vgaswitcheroo finally appears. Although the workaround may be easy, but it gets annoying really if I have to start the computer every time.

Now, I'm thinking of submitting a bug to launchpad, but not sure if this really is a bug (or what package it is, if it is a bug)

I do have a custom startup script though in /etc/rc.local, it simply turns off the ATI card (when vgaswitcheroo exists). It looks like this, and it might pose an impact to my problem:

```
until [ -e /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch ]; do
   : # do absolutely nothing
done

chmod a+rx /sys/kernel/debug
chmod a+w /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

any help / advice would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is your problem but you definitely need to mount the debugfs:

`sudo mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug/`

After that the needed files should hopefully appear.

To make the debugfs visible permanently you have to add an entry to your `/etc/fstab` that always mounts the debugfs at boot time. Sorry, but I am a  bit lazy to look up the exact line that you would need to put in your `/etc/fstab` but I hope this helps anyway.

Comment: Looks like the debugfs is already mounted because the command is reporting

`mount: none already mounted or /sys/kernel/debug busy
mount: according to mtab, none is already mounted on /sys/kernel/debug`

It seems like the GPU itself is not being detected by the kernel because running lspci | grep VGA reports only 1 GPU

But I really appreciate the response! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to check kernel parameters while it loads (when you see a GRUB screen on boot) - if there is a `nomodeset` parameter, you must delete it.